# Crossfilter barchart does not render

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I am new to Crossfilter and JS. I can't figure out why this barchart won't render. I've tried several date formats. Link to my jsfiddle is below. Any help, please?

It is basically reading a loan dataset in JSON format and attempting to barchart the count by day over time.

https://jsfiddle.net/5q1dddgt/2/

```
<div id="time-chart"></div>


/**
 * Created on 3/13/17.
 */
var mortgageJson = [{
  "index": 0,
  "full_fips": "04013",
  "defaulted_balance": 0.0,
  "original_balance": 148000.0,
  "county_name": "Maricopa County",
  "state": "AZ",
  "oltv": 79,
  "dti": 30.0,
  "originationMth": "1999-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "defaultRate": 0.0
}, {
  "index": 1,
  "full_fips": "04021",
  "defaulted_balance": 0.0,
  "original_balance": 148000.0,
  "county_name": "Pinal County",
  "state": "AZ",
  "oltv": 79,
  "dti": 30.0,
  "originationMth": "1999-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "defaultRate": 0.0
 }];

var mortgageSummary = mortgageJson;
var dateformat=d3.time.format("%m-%d-%Y");
mortgageSummary.forEach(function(d) {
    d.originationMonth = new      Date(d.originationMth).toLocaleDateString("en-GB");
});

var ndx = crossfilter(mortgageSummary);
var dateDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return d["originationMonth"];
});

var originationByTime = dateDim.group().reduceCount(function(d) {        return    d.originationMonth;});
var totalOrigination = ndx.groupAll().reduceSum(function(d) {
return d["original_balance"];
});

var max_county = originationByTime.top(1)[0].value;
var minDate = dateDim.bottom(1)[0]["originationMonth"];
var maxDate = dateDim.top(1)[0]["originationMonth"];
console.log(minDate);
console.log(maxDate);

var timeChart = dc.barChart("#time-chart");

timeChart
  .width(600)
  .height(160)
  .margins({
   top: 10,
   right: 50,
   bottom: 30,
   left: 50
})
.dimension(dateDim)
.group(originationByTime)
.transitionDuration(500)
.x(d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]))
.xUnits(d3.time.days)
.elasticX(true)
.elasticY(true)
  .xAxisLabel("Year")
  .yAxis().ticks(4);
 dc.renderAll();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the browser console and you'll see some of the problems. Your inclusion of firebug-lite is causing lots of errors. I'd recommend you just use the developer tools included in your browser.

Other changes:

You want an actual date object as your dimension rather than a string, so I changed

```
mortgageSummary.forEach(function(d) {
    d.originationMonth = new Date(d.originationMth).toLocaleDateString("en-GB");
});
```

to

```
mortgageSummary.forEach(function(d) {
    d.originationMonth = new Date(d.originationMth);
});
```

And `group.reduceCount` doesn't take any arguments (`reduceSum` does), so this will work fine:

```
var originationByTime = dateDim.group().reduceCount();
```

I also included dc.css as a dependency, which helps a lot with formatting.

Here's the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/5q1dddgt/4/

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and for your time!